# Using MySQL 3.x and 5.x simultaneously from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver

How can I use MySQL 3.x and MySQL 5.x simultaneously from my Java application if the two versions need different versions of JDBC drivers but the driver class name is the same?

For MySQL 3.x I downloaded MySQL Connector/J 3.0.17 and for MySQL 5.x I have MySQL Connector/J 5.1.12. How can I use them both?

Comment: Have you tested the 5.x driver against the 3.x database? It _might_ be backwardly compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check whether (as mentioned by @DaveHowes +1) you can use JDBC driver for v5 with DB v3. It probably works. In this case you have no problem.

If it does not work you have to use separate class loaders for 2 connectors to 2 different DBs. So, neither v5 nor v3 JDBC driver will not be in "regular" classpath of your application. Instead you should create some kind of wrapper that will instantiate its own `UrlClassLoader`:  and start driver. The mentioned collector should expose API that allows you to perform JDBC query. I hope this will work. All this if you are using pure JDBC. If you are using some kind of tools (e.g. Hibernate, iBatis etc.) I wish you good luck :) and suggest to ask more specific question that mentions tool you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) only Connector/J 3.0 supports MySQL 3.0

Comment: Mark, MySQL doc for v 3.0 was written when this was the newest version. The doc means that MySQL 3 cannot work with *older* connector. Really, try the Connector 5 with DB 3. It really will probably work. If not, follow my other explanations.

Comment: That MySQL documentation is for MySQL 5.0, for Connector/J 3.1 and later it does not list MySQL 3.0 as being compatible!

Comment: I see. Anyway try! It does not cost money!

Comment: I could not use the 5.1.12 driver for the 3.x DB (throw insane errors when connecting "unclosed result set") but managed to use the 5.x database with the 3.0.17 driver. Tried it only for fun, but was shocked to see that worked.. When I tried connecting with SQL Workbench/J then the situation was just the opposite: had to connect with the 5.1.12 driver to the 3.x database.. no matter why, but it works, so thank you for the good answer!